# Rename project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

While am creating project from existing source code project name in eclipse is displayed as

com.example.name.activityName

I want to change it to Projectname

Please share any query related to this within stack overflow or with my issue..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package Explorer

Right click on the project then -> 
refactor ->
rename

Don't forget to save your work